# Yesod/Persistent field with Eq

Tags: entity, persistent, yesod

In the [Persistent chapter of the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent), a certain field is given an `Eq` suffix, but it is never explained why. In the Relations section, we see the following models:

```
Person
    name String
    deriving Show
Car
    ownerId PersonId Eq
    name String
    deriving Show
```

Soon after, we are shown:

```
Person
    name String
Store
    name String
PersonStore
    personId PersonId
    storeId StoreId
    UniquePersonStore personId storeId
```

Aside from the latter being many-to-many, what is the difference? I've gathered on IRC that the `Eq` suffix enables joining on that field. If that is the case, why would a person ever *not* want the `Eq` suffix? Are there any other cases that `Eq` should be used aside from relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I got rid of all of those... it's just a holdover from older days of Persistent where the `Eq` was required. These days, it doesn't do anything, and you can compare equality on *all* fields.

Equality testing can be used for a lot of cases, such as "find all posts by an author":

```
selectList [PostAuthor ==. userId] [Desc PostDate]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions, and for fixing the documentation, even!